# Snatch-grip Shoulder Rotation

Tags: weightlifting, mobility, snatch

When completing a snatch how should one be tensing/controlling their back/shoulders?

Should I be looking to inwardly rotate (bend the bar so the plates would end up in front of me? Or should it be the opposite, pushing elbows backwards?

Should I be trying to shrug up or down in the receiving position?

Answer (score 2):

Mike Burgener (Level 5 Senior International Weightlifting coach) uses the cue "Show your armpits" at the top of the snatch, meaning, as you suggest, you should put pressure on the bar as if bending the weights forward.

Also, you should always maintain active shoulders, meaning you use your muscles to lift the weight off of connective tissue. Shoulder blades should be pressed together. (Active shoulders during a pull up would be shoulder blades together, but shoulders down, because you are fighting gravity and not relying on connective tissue to hang.)